# SQL to check for all values in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in Oracle DB.

```
ID  VALUE
-----------
1   1  
1   2  
1   3   
2   1   
2   2  
3   1  
3   2  
3   3  
4   1
```

How can I select ID's which have all 3 values (1,2,3)

Comment: Does Value field contain anything other than 1,2,3?

Comment: Title is **SQL to check for all values in column** or **SQL to check for specific values in column**?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest option is generally something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1 id, 1 val from dual union all
  3    select 1 id, 2 val from dual union all
  4    select 1 id, 3 val from dual union all
  5    select 2 id, 1 val from dual union all
  6    select 2 id, 2 val from dual union all
  7    select 3 id, 1 val from dual union all
  8    select 3 id, 2 val from dual union all
  9    select 3 id, 3 val from dual union all
 10    select 4 id, 1 val from dual
 11  )
 12  select id
 13    from x
 14   where val in (1,2,3)
 15   group by id
 16* having count(distinct val) = 3
SQL> /

        ID
----------
         1
         3
```

The `WHERE` clause identifies the values you're interested in.  The `HAVING` clause tells you how many of those values need to exist.  If you wanted all the rows that had at least 2 of the 3 values, for example, you'd change the `HAVING` clause to look for a `COUNT` of 2.

If a particular `val` is guaranteed to occur at most once per `id`, you can eliminate the `distinct` in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM TABLENAME T
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM TABLENAME T1
                WHERE T1.ID = T.ID AND T1.VALUE = '1')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM TABLENAME T2
                WHERE T1.ID = T.ID AND T2.VALUE = '2')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM TABLENAME T3
                WHERE T1.ID = T.ID AND T2.VALUE = '3')
```

or

```
SELECT ID
  FROM TABLENAME T
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT( * )
          FROM (SELECT VALUE
                  FROM TABLENAME T1
                 WHERE T1.ID = T.ID
                GROUP BY VALUE)) = 3;
```

where 3 is number of values which can be calculated by a

```
        SELECT COUNT( * )
          FROM TABLENAME T1
        GROUP BY VALUE
```

so this will be general purpose:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM TABLENAME T
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT( * )
          FROM (SELECT VALUE
                  FROM TABLENAME T1
                 WHERE T1.ID = T.ID
                GROUP BY VALUE)) = (SELECT COUNT( * )
                                      FROM TABLENAME T2
                                    GROUP BY VALUE)
```

Comment: Valid, but overly complicated - the answer can be done in a single `SELECT` statement.  Also, your aliases need correcting

Comment: Still overly complicated - you don't need the subquery.  Hint: `HAVING`

Comment: I tried this.. but I am getting all the rows even though it doesnt have all the values 1,2 and 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option... each expression in the HAVING clause is counting the number of values that are found equal to 1, 2, or 3.  If any of these counts is less than 1, then the ID will not be returned.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00fdc/8

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
  SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 1, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
  SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 2, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
  SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 3, 1, 0)) > 0
```

**EDIT** - To require value 1, and either 2 or 3:

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
  SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 1, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
  (
      SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 2, 1, 0)) > 0 OR
      SUM(DECODE(VALUE, 3, 1, 0)) > 0
  )
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I see a HAVING in my statement.

Comment: Then why use SUM, when you can use COUNT ;)

Comment: If you COUNT, how do you leave out the values that are 0?  They will be counted, too.

Comment: It's time you looked at the documentation, rather than expect me to give you the answer

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.. It worked!! how about writing a query if value = 1 is mandatory and any one value present either 2 or 3

Comment: I've added this above... assuming you want it to return those that have 2 and 3 as well.  If you need to return those where 1 exists, and either 2 or 3 (but not both), then it needs to be revised.

Comment: Thanks Again.. This code is getting ID 4 which has value 1 but not either of 2 or 3. My requirement is that the value = 1 and it should have atleast another value either 2 or 3.

Comment: Yep, you're right... I think the statement I copied in was an older version I was working on.  I've updated it, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

select id from (select id,sum(case when value=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'v1',  
sum(case when value=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 'v2',    
sum(case when value=3 then 1 else 0 end) as 'v3'    
 from orac group by id) as final    
 where v1>0 and v2>0 and v3>0

Answer (score 1):

With this option you will get more than the IDs, up to your application to select the column you want:

```
SELECT ID,
  sum(CASE WHEN VALUE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
  sum(CASE WHEN VALUE = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
  sum(CASE WHEN VALUE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THREE
FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING ONE >= 1 AND TWO >= 1 AND THREE >= 1;
```

alternatively if your case is specific (only values 1, 2, 3 are possible, and no duplicate values are allowed), then you could try the following one:

```
SELECT ID,
  count(VALUE) AS VALUECOUNT
FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING VALUECOUNT = 3;
```

I would take care before going that way, as you might get side effects if later you want to add additional values. But it's still worth proposing if your current case fits the restrictions given above.

And, of course, if you don't like the idea of fetching these intermediate counts, enclose the queries I gave within another select

```
SELECT ID FROM (
  ...
)
```