# How to make check whether all elements exist in a table or not in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have any array of subject id in PHP, say

```
['abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232', ....]
```

Here is my false attempt in sql oracle

```
select
  *
from
  subject_table
where
  subject_id IN ('abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232'....)
```

If the subjects are there, return `true` else return `false`

How do I achieve it?

Comment: You want to return True only when all three subjects are present not just one or two

Comment: @JSapkota, currently, I don't know how to write the sql, which only returns true, when 3 subjects are there.

Comment: @Pரதீப், I am not sure how to write the sql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle sql return true if exists question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098800/oracle-sql-return-true-if-exists-question)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681083/sql-to-check-for-all-values-in-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a distinct count to know whether all subject_ids where there.

```
select case when count(distinct subject_id) = 3 then 'true' else 'false' end as status 
  from subject_table
 where subject_id in('abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232')
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select
  case when count(1) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end
from
  subject_table
where
  subject_id IN ('abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232')
```

Comment: Will give a go.

Comment: this checks only if *any* element exists in table, not if *all* elements exist in table

Answer (score 0):

If you set > 0 is true, 0 is false you can select like this:

```
select count(*)  as Existed
from
  subject_table
where
  subject_id IN ('abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232'....)
```

Comment: Question is, if *all* values are in the table. With your solution you must finally compare the result `count(*)` with the amount of commited parameters `'abc123', 'bcd3432' ...`  This will only work, if subject_id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array as a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM   subject_table
              WHERE  StringList( 'abc123', 'bcd3432', 'bla232' )
                     SUBMULTISET OF
                     CAST( COLLECT( subject_id ) AS StringList )
            )
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS has_all_ids
FROM   DUAL;
```

You can even use a [bind parameter to pass the array in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.php):

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM   subject_table
              WHERE  :your_array
                     SUBMULTISET OF
                     CAST( COLLECT( subject_id ) AS StringList )
            )
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS has_all_ids
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Here I am splitting the string containing all the elements as a set of rows and comparing it with the main table with a `LEFT JOIN`

```
WITH     given_sub
     AS (    SELECT DISTINCT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('abc123,bcd3432,bla232',
                                                  '[^,]+',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL))
                                subject_id
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY INSTR ('abc123,bcd3432,bla232',
                           ',',
                           1,
                           LEVEL - 1) > 0)
SELECT CASE
          WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT s.subject_id) < COUNT (DISTINCT g.subject_id)
          THEN
             'FALSE'
          ELSE
             'TRUE'
       END
          All_found
  FROM given_sub g
       LEFT OUTER JOIN subject_table s
          ON     s.subject_id = g.subject_id
             AND s.subject_id IN ('abc123',
                                  'bcd3432',
                                  'bla232'
                                  );
```